Loading Spinner Implementation
I've recently implemented a loading spinner for my web application and would greatly appreciate your feedback on the code. The spinner is supposed to display while data is being fetched from the server, providing a better user experience. I'm looking for suggestions on improving the code's efficiency, readability, and overall performance.
I'm also encountering an issue with my loading service where I'm using a delay to avoid an NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.
app.component.html
@if (loading$ | async) {
  <ng-container>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <app-spinner></app-spinner>
  </ng-container>
}
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

loading.service.ts
export class LoadingService {
  private _loading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public readonly loading$ = this._loading.asObservable().pipe(delay(1));
  constructor() { }

  public show() {
    this._loading.next(true);
  }

  public hide() {
    this._loading.next(false);
  }
}

network.interceptor.ts
export const networkInterceptorFn: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  let totalRequests = 0;
  let requestsCompleted = 0;

  const loadingService = inject(LoadingService);

  loadingService.show();
  totalRequests++;

  return next(req).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      requestsCompleted++;

      if (requestsCompleted === totalRequests) {
        loadingService.hide();
        totalRequests = 0;
        requestsCompleted = 0;
      }
    })
  );
};

